# Pandas - Optimizing a search function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have a dataframe with the following data:

| id | datetime | IPorig | IPdest | State | sTtl | dTtl | SynAck |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39 | 1692706623.76113 | 31.13.85.49 | 192.168.2.200 | FIN | 83.00000 | 64.00000 | 0.00000 |
| 40 | 1692706623.76173 | 192.168.2.6 | 40.70.161.102 | CON | 64.00000 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 |
| 41 | 1692706623.76235 | 177.53.94.198 | 192.168.8.11 | RST | 54.00000 | 64.00000 | 0.00000 |
| 42 | 1692706623.76270 | 192.168.6.88 | 104.89.245.234 | CON | 64.00000 | 47.00000 | 0.14916 |
| 43 | 1692706623.76310 | 192.168.7.19 | 104.244.42.195 | CON | 64.00000 | 53.00000 | 0.00000 |
| 44 | 1692706623.76320 | 142.250.218.163 | 192.168.0.197 | CON | 118.00000 | 64.00000 | 0.00000 |
| 45 | 1692706623.76484 | 192.168.7.19 | 104.244.42.2 | CON | 64.00000 | 53.00000 | 0.00000 |
| 46 | 1692706623.76595 | 172.217.30.170 | 192.168.1.100 | CON | 118.00000 | 64.00000 | 0.00000 |
| 47 | 1692706623.76755 | 160.19.240.141 | 192.168.3.151 | CON | 119.00000 | 64.00000 | 0.00000 |
| 48 | 1692706623.76780 | 179.183.28.32 | 192.168.10.186 | RST | 78.00000 | 64.00000 | 0.00000 |
| 49 | 1692706623.76790 | 179.183.28.32 | 192.168.10.186 | RST | 78.00000 | 64.00000 | 0.00000 |

I have the following function:

```
def rbt(saddr,state,time):
    sub_df = df.loc[(df['IPorig'] == saddr) & (state == 'RST') & (df['State'] == 'RST') & (df['datetime'] < stime) & (df['datetime'] > (stime - 300))]
    count = len(sub_df)
    if count > 10:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Run:

```
df['rbt'] = df.apply(lambda x: rbt(x['IPorig'], x['State'], x['datetime']), axis=1)
```

As my dataframe has these specifications, this function is taking forever. How can I optimize it?

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4827996 entries, 0 to 4827995
Data columns (total 55 columns):
```

If there's another way to retrieve the count of flows for a specific IP, state, and time interval more efficiently, in order to add a column to the dataframe.

Comment: Your example input is a quite poor choice, because (a) it can't be run by answerers in this format and (b) the time range is much less than 300 seconds, so your last predicate will always be true

Comment: I can't input 4 million data points here, and any example wouldn't come close to the size of my dataframe. The above example is just for illustration...

Comment: I apologize for that... I've already fixed the lambda function

Comment: You don't need to input 4 million points; what you _do_ need to do (if you want reliable answers) is to show a representative excerpt - in Python, not as a table - that exercises all of your predicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wild guess; option 1 using a manual datetime range:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

data = '''
id  datetime    IPorig  IPdest  State   sTtl    dTtl    SynAck
39  1692706623.76113    31.13.85.49 192.168.2.200   FIN 83.00000    64.00000    0.00000
40  1692706623.76173    192.168.2.6 40.70.161.102   CON 64.00000    0.00000 0.00000
41  1692706623.76235    177.53.94.198   192.168.8.11    RST 54.00000    64.00000    0.00000
42  1692706623.76270    192.168.6.88    104.89.245.234  CON 64.00000    47.00000    0.14916
43  1692706623.76310    192.168.7.19    104.244.42.195  CON 64.00000    53.00000    0.00000
44  1692706623.76320    142.250.218.163 192.168.0.197   CON 118.00000   64.00000    0.00000
45  1692706623.76484    192.168.7.19    104.244.42.2    CON 64.00000    53.00000    0.00000
46  1692706623.76595    172.217.30.170  192.168.1.100   CON 118.00000   64.00000    0.00000
47  1692706623.76755    160.19.240.141  192.168.3.151   CON 119.00000   64.00000    0.00000
48  1692706623.76780    179.183.28.32   192.168.10.186  RST 78.00000    64.00000    0.00000
49  1692706623.76790    179.183.28.32   192.168.10.186  RST 78.00000    64.00000    0.00000
'''

with StringIO(data) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', index_col='id')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], unit='s')

is_rst = df.loc[
    df['State'] == 'RST',
    ['datetime', 'IPorig'],
].reset_index()

# Can't use merge_asof because of the datetime inequality
merged = pd.merge(
    left=is_rst, right=is_rst, on='IPorig',
)
time_diff = merged['datetime_y'] - merged['datetime_x']
result_idx = merged.loc[
    (time_diff > pd.Timedelta(0)) &
    (time_diff < pd.Timedelta(300, unit='s')),
    'id_x',
].unique()

# Dataframe for which the predicates evaluate true
rbt = df.loc[result_idx]

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
print(rbt)
```

```
                        datetime         IPorig          IPdest State  sTtl  dTtl  SynAck
id                                                                                       
48 2023-08-22 12:17:03.767800064  179.183.28.32  192.168.10.186   RST  78.0  64.0     0.0
```

Option 2 (preferred) using `merge_asof`:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

data = '''
id  datetime    IPorig  IPdest  State   sTtl    dTtl    SynAck
39  1692706623.76113    31.13.85.49 192.168.2.200   FIN 83.00000    64.00000    0.00000
40  1692706623.76173    192.168.2.6 40.70.161.102   CON 64.00000    0.00000 0.00000
41  1692706623.76235    177.53.94.198   192.168.8.11    RST 54.00000    64.00000    0.00000
42  1692706623.76270    192.168.6.88    104.89.245.234  CON 64.00000    47.00000    0.14916
43  1692706623.76310    192.168.7.19    104.244.42.195  CON 64.00000    53.00000    0.00000
44  1692706623.76320    142.250.218.163 192.168.0.197   CON 118.00000   64.00000    0.00000
45  1692706623.76484    192.168.7.19    104.244.42.2    CON 64.00000    53.00000    0.00000
46  1692706623.76595    172.217.30.170  192.168.1.100   CON 118.00000   64.00000    0.00000
47  1692706623.76755    160.19.240.141  192.168.3.151   CON 119.00000   64.00000    0.00000
48  1692706623.76780    179.183.28.32   192.168.10.186  RST 78.00000    64.00000    0.00000
49  1692706623.76790    179.183.28.32   192.168.10.186  RST 78.00000    64.00000    0.00000
'''

with StringIO(data) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', index_col='id')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], unit='s')

is_rst = df.loc[
    df['State'] == 'RST',
    ['datetime', 'IPorig'],
].reset_index()

result_idx = pd.merge_asof(
    left=is_rst, right=is_rst, by='IPorig', on='datetime',
    tolerance=pd.Timedelta(300, unit='s'),
    allow_exact_matches=False,
)['id_y'].dropna()

# Dataframe for which the predicates evaluate true
rbt = df.loc[result_idx]

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
print(rbt)
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't very clear in my question, but I need to add a column called 'rbt' to my dataframe, and the information in this field refers to flow data from the last 300 seconds. If the search threshold is exceeded, it receives a value of 1; otherwise, it gets a value of 0. The issue I'm facing is that when I run this function, it runs indefinitely, as if it enters an infinite loop.

Comment: Have you tried running the above? This is what it does. If you really want 0/1 output, use the index I generated to perform an assignment.

Comment: KeyError: 'id_y'

Comment: Either your code doesn't match what's shown here, or you need to upgrade Pandas